# How to get a High quality portable render of an arbitrary sized html document?

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to design a poster using HTML, currently CSS allows me to get a huge canvas (90cmx200cm), but I can't get a document to send for printing.

Chromium does not allow using custom paper size and Firefox let me use the required size (on non-standard inches) but fails miserably to render a high quality PDF (Even 20px text that looks good when browsing w/o zoom).

I was thinking that I should be able to get a lower level interaction with the renderer to get this done.
The output format is irrelevant as long as it's portable enough.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to know. Firstly print quality is related to dots-per-inch. Best software and printer in the world isn't going to make a 100 x 100 pixels photo print quality.

http://www.vsellis.com/understanding-dpi-resolution-and-print-vs-web-images/

Images on web pages are rasterized images, and typically quite low resolution (compressed formats such as JPEG and PNG to reduce bandwidth use). You might try using high-resolution images and scaling them with CSS (I have not idea how this will print though).

Make sure all of your text is actually text (don't use images).

To improve quality ensure images are high resolution. If possible you could explore using SVG, which is a loss-less format for diagrams and line drawings. I believe this should be preserved if you print to PDF. There are also third party libraries that convert SVG to PDF.

Comment: I was planning on using SVGs for the images (=, but this should be a good tip for newcomers if we get this working.

When I said it was low quality it was based on the font, that happened even when rendering the text on a non-colossal size (15px), it seemed like Firefox rendered a zoomed out version of my test document. I will clarify that. Thanks for making me notice this overlooked detail.